# Printing null character when input is odd character amount

Tags: c++, c, null

I've been toying with this c program for a while, and I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

In the very bottom of my code, I have a function that replaces every other word with a "-".
My problem is that when I enter an odd numbered word, such as "Cat", "dog", "hamburger", it will place a "-" in what I think is the null character position, though I have not been able to debunk it.

Thank you for your help!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    void replace(char w[]);

    int main( )
    {
        char w[100], x[100], y[100];
        int z = 0;

    printf("Player 1, please enter the secret word: ");
    fgets(x,100,stdin); 

//    system("clear");  

    while( strcmp(x,y) != 0 )
    {
        strcpy(w,x);
     //   printf("\nLength of String : %d", strlen(w)-1);
        replace(w);
        printf("Player 2, the word is %s\n",w);
        printf("Player 2, please guess the word: ");
        fgets(y,100,stdin);
        z++;
        if( strcmp(x,y) != 0 )
        {
            printf("Wrong. Try again.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            //system("clear");
            printf("Correct!\n");
            printf("It took you %d attempt(s).\n",z);
            switch (z)
            {
                case 1 :
                case 2 :     
                     printf("A. Awesome work!");
                     {break;}

                case 3 :
                case 4 :
                     printf("B. Best, that was!");
                     {break;}

                case 5 :
                case 6 :
                     printf("C. Concentrate next time!");
                     {break;}

                case 7 :
                     printf("D. Don't quit your day job.");
                     {break;}

                default :
                     printf("F. Failure.");
                     {break;}
            }
        }
    }
        getch();
}

void replace(char w[])
{
    int a;

    a = 0;
    while (w[a] != '\0')
    {
        if (a % 2 != 0)
        {
            w[a] = '-';
            a++;
        }
        if (w[a] != '\0')
        {
            a++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better if you give sample input and output that are expected and getting currently.

Comment: if `a % 2 != 0` and not end of string, a will increment by 2, is that you want?

Comment: @moeCake That is correct. I am looking to increment "a" by two.

Comment: @Chinna for instance, if I were to input "Cat" the output is "C-t-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement like this...

```
int a;
int len;
a = 0;
len = strlen(w);
if(len%2 == 0)
    len = len-1;
while (len!=a)
{
    if (a % 2 != 0)
    {
        w[a] = '-';
        a++;
    }
    if (w[a] != '\0')
    {
        a++;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [`fgets manual`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets);

> **fgets()** reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. ***If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.*** A terminating null byte (\0) is stored after the last character in the buffer.

The newline entered is what you're replacing.

Comment: So you're suggesting that I use something other than fgets()?

Comment: You can add one more check if string end is newline, replace it with '\0'.

Comment: @user3109767 Not necessarily. You could either remove any newline before running `remove` by just checking if the last character is newline and if so set it to `\0`, or you could modify your existing loop to check for line feed to and remove it if found.

Answer (score 0):

I think replacing `fgets` with just `gets` will work:
Try:

`//fgets(x,100,stdin);`

`gets(x);`

and

`//fgets(y,100,stdin);`

```
gets(y);
```

That will be enough I think.

Comment: `gets()` is frowned upon because it does not do bounds checking and is a security risk from buffer overflow attacks.  Trimming the newline off of the results of `fgets()` is a safer solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the additional '\n' character in the char array passed to the replace function.

For instance, when the input is "Cat", the passed char[] w contains {'C', 'a', 't', '\n', '\0'};
The additional '\n' also gets replaced with "-" character.

The following will solve this problem.

```
while (w[a] != '\0')
{

    if (w[a] != '\0' && w[a] != '\n')
    {
        if (a % 2 != 0)
        {
            w[a] = '-';
        }
        a++;
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a bit of an aside, can I suggest structuring your replace() code differently

```
void replace(char charw[])
{
int length=strlen(charw);
int i;
for (i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
    if (i%2==1)  /*yes, i%2 would also work, but lets not get too clever*/
        {charw[i]='-';}
    }
}
```

This is far more readable.  Breaking in the middle of a loop...not so much.